# Is there an easy way to scrub back and forth through a series of plots with matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas DataFrame from which I can create a plot for every row. **I'd like to be able to render the plot, and then ideally use some kind of slider to roll forward and backward through the rows of the DataFrame so I can visualize how the data change across rows.**

One way I could do this is to render all the images and create a video, but then I don't know of a video player where I can scrub frame by frame. If there is such a thing, that would likely solve my problem.

Comment: it is easier to display back and forth images instead of video.

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to do this in matplotlib. But there are other libraries like Bokeh that enable more interactive visualization.

Comment: If you use an interactive backend (e.g., notebook, QT, Tk) you can do this in native matplotlib

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for an interactive plot. There are several libraries out there which can do this. I have used Bokeh for this kind of task before and it will be pretty easy for you to do that using their online documentation. You can use a slider or a text field for the row number and render the plot in real time.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html